# Basic bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot 2 variables in a basic bar chart.

I have a list of odds and finishing position. I am trying to chart odds by finishing position.

```
Odds    Finish Position
5       6 
6       5
3       3
4       2
2       4
1.8     1
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(data.combined, aes(x = Odds)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = finish_pos))
```

But it shows as one very small line. How can I adjust? My data has about 1000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this using `geom_line`?

```
require(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(x = Finish_Position, y = Odds)) + geom_line();
```

[image]

Or using `geom_bar`?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Finish_Position, y = Odds)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity");
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "Odds    Finish_Position
5       6
6       5
3       3
4       2
2       4
1.8     1", header = T)
```

`str(data.combined)` results in:

```
$ row_id          : Factor w/ 1132 levels "2017-03-04_Flemington_9_ Gunn Island_False",..: 10 3 7 5 2 4 6 8 9 1 ...
$ entry_id        : Factor w/ 100 levels "2017-03-04_9_False",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Odds            : num  38 10 3.95 7.2 12.5 4 42 65 7.8 60 ...
$ BP              : int  1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 ...
$ offset          : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ horse_win       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
$ horse_wp        : int  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
$ min_races       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ days_since      : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
$ last_race_res   : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
$ last_race_wp    : int  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ last_three_races: int  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
$ horse_dist_win  : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ horse_dist_wp   : int  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
$ horse_track_win : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ horse_track_wp  : int  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
$ horse_going_win : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
$ horse_going_wp  : int  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
$ finish_pos      : int  6 9 2 5 8 1 4 3 7 10 ...

summary(data.combined$Odds) results in:

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.47    8.00   17.00   39.93   40.00  910.00
```

Comment: When I plot my data with geom_bar, the odds column goes from 0,2000,4,000,6000 even though my numbers are not that high.

Comment: How can I get the scale to be much smaller like yours above?

Comment: @Matt You can add e.g. `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1000))` to your `ggplot` call.

Comment: @Matt: or `+ ylim(0, 1000)`.

Comment: ggplot(data.combined, aes(x = finish_pos, y = Odds)) + + ylim(0, 1000) + geom_bar(stat = "identity");

Comment: @Matt You've got a double `"+"`. Try `ggplot(data.combined, aes(x = finish_pos, y = Odds)) + ylim(0, 1000) + geom_bar(stat = "identity");`

Comment: I used: ggplot(data.combined, aes(x = finish_pos, y = Odds)) + ylim(0, 1000) + geom_bar(stat = "identity"); now it says "removed 683 rows containing missing values" but I know each row has a value for odds and finishing position?

Comment: `ylim` will *filter* entries, whereas `coord_cartesian` will *zoom* in/out (using the full data) (see `?ylim` and `?coord_cartesian` for details). `ggplot` adjusting your scale automatically to go all the way up to `6000` suggests that you in fact have very large values in your `dataframe`. You can check with `summary`. Perhaps it makes sense to first try and understand where those large numbers (outliers?) come from?

Comment: the largest number I have in the odds column is 910 so I am not sure where this is coming from

Comment: the summary confirms this also so I am unsure how to proceed?

Comment: @Matt It's difficult to troubleshoot without the actual data. Can you please edit your original post to include the output of `str(data.combined)` and `summary(data.combined$Odds)`. Either way, `ylim` or `coord_cartesian` will allow you to adjust the y scale. So this should work regardless.

Comment: this also doesn't give me a count of finishing position which is what I am looking for. E.g. I know in my data that count of 1st place is around 5 for odds less than 2. Do I need to create a count column in my data?

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure what you mean; nor do I understand (anymore) what you actually want to plot. I think it would be beneficial if you could provide a mock-up/plot of your expected outcome. I thought you wanted to plot `Odds` as a function of `finishing_position`. Now you are talking about the *"count of the finishing position"*. What is that?

Comment: it is a count of each of the finishing positions based on the odds, in Excel in a pivot table it would look like what I have added above in my initial post - I am not sure how to display that graphically though.

Comment: thank you, the above comments have helped me resolve the issue.